# In a CSV file, how can a Python coder remove all but an X number of duplicates across rows?

Tags: sorting, csv, python-3.x

Here is an example CSV file for this problem:

```
Jack,6
Sam,10
Milo,9
Jacqueline,7
Sam,5
Sam,8
Sam,10
```

Let's take the context to be the names and scores of a quiz these people took. We can see that Sam has taken this quiz 4 times but I want to only have an X number of the same person's result (**They also need to be the most recent entries**). Let's assume we wanted no more than 3 of the same person's results.

I realised it probably wouldn't be possible to achieve having no more than 3 of each person's result without some extra information. Here is the updated CSV file:

```
Jack,6,1793
Sam,10,2079
Milo,9,2132
Jacqueline,7,2590
Sam,5,2881
Sam,8,3001
Sam,10,3013
```

The third column is essentially the number of seconds from the "Epoch", which is a reference point for time. With this, I thought I could simply sort the file in terms of lowest to highest for the epoch column and use set() to remove all but a certain number of duplicates for the name column while also removing the removed persons score as well.

In theory, this should leave me with the 3 most recent results per person but in practice, I have no idea how I could adapt the set() function to do this unless there is some alternative way. So my question is, what possible methods are there to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of a `list`, and each time you add an entry check the length of the list: if it's more than three items `pop` the first one off (or do the check after cycling through the file).  This assumes the file is in time sequence.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# looping over a csv file gives one row at a time
# so we will emulate that
raw_data = [
    ('Jack', '6'),
    ('Sam', '10'),
    ('Milo', '9'),
    ('Jacqueline', '7'),
    ('Sam', '5'),
    ('Sam', '8'),
    ('Sam', '10'),
    ]

# this will hold our information, and works by providing an empty
# list for any missing key
student_data = defaultdict(list)
for row in raw_data:  # note 1
    # separate the row into its component items, and convert
    # score from str to int
    name, score = row
    score = int(score)
    # get the current list for the student, or a brand-new list
    student = student_data[name]
    student.append(score)
    # after addeng the score to the end, remove the first scores
    # until we have no more than three items in the list
    if len(student) > 3:
        student.pop(0)

# print the items for debugging
for item in student_data.items():
    print(item)
```

which results in:

```
('Milo', [9])
('Jack', [6])
('Sam', [5, 8, 10])
('Jacqueline', [7])
```

---

Note 1:  to use an actual csv file you want code like this:

```
raw_file = open('some_file.csv')
csv_file = csv.reader(raw_file)
for row in csv_file:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't quite understand how this would work if the "raw data" was a CSV file. I'd be very grateful if you could explain how exactly your code works, perhaps with comments in the code please?

Comment: @Roughbladez: Updated answer, and you're welcome.  :)

Answer (score 0):

To handle the timestamps, and as an alternative, you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby, islice
from operator import itemgetter

raw_data = [
    ('Jack','6','1793'),
    ('Sam','10','2079'),
    ('Milo','9','2132'),
    ('Jacqueline','7','2590'),
    ('Sam','5','2881'),
    ('Sam','8','3001'),
    ('Sam','10','3013'),
    ]

# Sort by name in natural order, then by timestamp from highest to lowest
sorted_data = sorted(raw_data, key=lambda x: x[0], -int(x[2]))

# Group by user
grouped = groupby(sorted_data, key=itemgetter(0))
# And keep only three most recent values for each user
most_recent = [(k, [v for _, v, _ in islice(grp, 3)]) for k, grp in grouped]
```